# How can I pass more than 10 command line parameter to jmeter command line run?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, distributed

I need to pass more than 10 parameters in jmeter command line run. But if I go more than 10 the jmeter command line gives error. As I am using distributed mode I cannot use properties file to give parameter. Can some body suggest me a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [JMeter User Manual](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)

> G, --globalproperty =
>
> Define Global properties (sent to servers)
>
> e.g. -Gport=123
>
> or **-Gglobal.properties**

So you can create `global.properties` file and define your values like:

```
param1=value1
param2=value2
param3=value3
etc.
```

Once done you should be able to access the properties on remote slaves via [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) like `${__P(param1)}`

More information: [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter)

Comment: As I tried with simple property file I need to keep the file in every slave machine, is it the same with globla.properties or will it ok if I keep this file only one where I run the test from?

Comment: It should be enough to have this file only on **master** node

Answer (score 1):

if you are not running in distributed mode u can't use -G option in this case

1. Create a property file eg loadtest.properties (D:/PT/loadtest/loadtest.properties).
2. Add your parameters

```html
Thread1=10
Thread2=20
Thread3=30
Thread4=10 
Thread5=20
Thread6=30
Thread7=10 
Thread8=20 
Thread9=30 
Thread10=10
Thread12=20
```

3. use -q option with file name

```html
    jmeter -n -t {path of jmx file}/abc.jmx -l {path of jtl file}.jtl -q D:/PT/loadtest/loadtest.properties
```